# Description of sign's "K" warning when performing apt command

Tags: apt, snap

Every time I perform an apt command (fi `sudo apt install <package-name>` I receive the following warning messages regarding snap:

```
sudo apt-get install supertux
Pakketlijsten worden ingelezen... Klaar
Boom van vereisten wordt opgebouwd       
De statusinformatie wordt gelezen... Klaar
De volgende extra pakketten zullen geïnstalleerd worden:
  libsdl2-image-2.0-0 supertux-data
2018/11/06 11:15:08.533901 main.go:150: description of sign's "k" is lowercase: "naam van de te gebruiken sleutel, gebruik anders de standaardsleutel"
2018/11/06 11:15:08.534162 main.go:150: description of install's "dangerous" is lowercase: "installeer het opgegeven snapbestand zelfs indien er geen vooraf erkende handtekeningen voor zijn, hetgeen betekent dat het niet werd geverifieerd en dus gevaarlijk zou kunnen zijn (--devmode impliceert dit)"
De volgende NIEUWE pakketten zullen geïnstalleerd worden:
  libsdl2-image-2.0-0 supertux supertux-data
0 opgewaardeerd, 3 nieuw geïnstalleerd, 0 te verwijderen en 0 niet opgewaardeerd.
Er moeten 83,8 MB aan archieven opgehaald worden.
Na deze bewerking zal er 135 MB extra schijfruimte gebruikt worden.
Wilt u doorgaan? [J/n]
```

My own translation of the error lines regarding snap:

```
2018/11/06 10:21:08.236205 main.go:150: description of sign's "k" is lowercase: "name of the key in use, use the default key"
2018/11/06 10:21:08.236582 main.go:150: description of install's "dangerous" is lowercase: "Install the snap even if there are no recognized keys which means that these were not verified and could be potentially dangerous (--devmode implies this")
```

I remember installing some snaps with this `--devmode` switch but cannot tell which. How can I search for them and uninstall?

Comment: Try running your command again, prefixed with `LANG=C` (like `LANG=C sudo apt install whatever`) to directly get the default English output. Free translations of error messages are hard to research and verify. You can then [edit] your question to update it. Also please paste the complete output of an example command that generates this error, not just a part of it. There might be relevant context.

Comment: I've tried this but strangely it omits the error lines regarding snap in that case. I've put the complete output in Dutch and added my own translation below.

Comment: Yep, here too... If I do `LANG=C sudo apt autoremove` I get the normal output, but without setting LANG, I get these same errors. In Dutch (which is my locale too) so it seems these errors are related to locale settings? Is that only in nl_NL or all other non US locales? Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the same issue reported on the snapcraft forum around two weeks ago [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/weird-error-message-whenever-i-run-the-snap-command/6418/12).

Seems to be a combination of incorrect translations in `snap`, causing it to print these warnings, and an incorrect script in `apt` that should hide these internal warnings...

A forum moderator called "chipaca" advised to change that internal `apt` script so that it correctly hides warnings from `snap` in that place, as intended. Quoting [their reply](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/weird-error-message-whenever-i-run-the-snap-command/6418/16):

> Ok, so the bug is in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf`. It isn’t redirecting standard error as it should.
>   It looks like this:
>
> ```
> AptCli::Hooks::Install { "[ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap || true"; };
> ```
>
> and you want it to look like this:
>
> ```
> AptCli::Hooks::Install { "[ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true"; };
> ```
>
> the best way would be to just edit that file and add the needed redirection. If that seems too arcane, you could also run
>
> ```
> sudo perl -pi~ -we 's|from-apt|from-apt 2>/dev/null|' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
> ```
>
> which should do the edit for you (and leave a backup of the old file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf~` just in case). But you probably shouldn’t be running arbitrary commands from some rando on an internet forum. I hear it’s bad for your teeth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will not try it however as I don't want to change something structurally to apt, after all it's just an annoyance. I've accepted your answer even though.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue as this is already the contents of the 20snapd.conf file

#AptCli::Hooks::Install { "[ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true"; };
AptCli::Hooks::Install { "[ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true"; };